# Blender: Creating Material, Texture, and open image...

Tags: python, textures, blender

Well, in Blender, how can I create a new material, assign it to the current object, create an image texture and assign it and then open an image for it (and also open the image in the UV/Image Editor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading the [Blender API Python Cookbook](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets) on the Blender wiki. It has sections for each of the features that you want with code examples.

Comment: See if you can help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293835/blender-segmentation-fault-core-dumped